# How to understand Wireshark ICMP data size

Tags: networking, ping, wireshark

When I send a `ping` from Linux specifying 8972 bytes, the command output looks like this:

```
PING 192.168.100.100 (192.168.100.100) 8972(9000) bytes of data.
```

That 9014 number includes the 8 byte ICMP header plus 20 byte IP header.  `tcpdump` agrees, showing the packet like this, excluding the IP header:

```
IP 192.168.100.1 > 192.168.100.100: ICMP echo request, id 23220, seq 1, length 8980
```

Wireshark agrees with the 8980 number, but it also shows 8964 bytes of data inside.  What is that number; why isn't it 8972?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Linux *iputils* `ping` command usually puts a timestamp in the first 8 bytes of the payload. Wireshark's dissector tries to interpret this, and shows those 8 bytes as a *separate field* – note "Timestamp from icmp data" in your screenshot.

If you use other tools such as `nping --icmp --data-len 56`, this additional field will not show up and the entire 56 bytes will be shown as the payload.